# Swig from C: Error: Syntax error in input(1)

Tags: c, cmake, swig

I'm very new to SWIG (as a matter of fact this is my first "project" using it) and I've come across an error I don't really understand.
I've been trying to use SWIG over a very small piece of C code like so :

**src/fft.c**

```
#include "fft.h"
void separate(double complex *a, int n)
{
  ...
}

void fft2(double complex *x, int n)
{
  ...
}
```

**src/fft.h**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <complex.h>
#include <math.h>
void separate(double complex *a, int n);
void fft2(double complex *x, int n);
```

Here is my swig interface file :

**src/swig/fft.i**

```
%module fft
%{
#include "fft.h"
%}
%include "fft.h"
```

As I use CMake as build system here are the CMakeLists.txt files

**src/CMakeLists.txt**

```
add_library(
    fft SHARED
    fft.c
)

set_target_properties(fft PROPERTIES VERSION ${PROJECT_VERSION})
set_target_properties(fft PROPERTIES PUBLIC_HEADER "fft.h")

add_subdirectory(swig)
```

**src/swig/CMakeLists.txt**

```
find_package(SWIG REQUIRED)
include(${SWIG_USE_FILE})

add_subdirectory(python)
```

**src/swig/python/CMakeLists.txt**

```
find_package(PythonLibs REQUIRED)
include_directories(${PYTHON_INCLUDE_PATH})

set(CMAKE_SWIG_FLAGS "")
set_source_files_properties(../fft.i PROPERTIES CPLUSPLUS ON)
include_directories(../..)

swig_add_library(fft LANGUAGE python SOURCES ../fft.i)
swig_link_libraries(fft ${PROJECT_NAME} ${PYTHON_LIBRARIES})
```

And here is the output of both `cmake ..` and `make` in the `build` directory :

**cmake**

```
-- The C compiler identification is AppleClang 10.0.0.10001044
-- The CXX compiler identification is AppleClang 10.0.0.10001044
-- Check for working C compiler: 
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: 
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: 
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: 
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Found SWIG: /usr/local/bin/swig (found version "4.0.0") 
-- Found PythonLibs:
/usr/local/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/ \
lib/libpython3.7m.dylib (found version "3.7.0") 
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: 
/Users/simon/Documents/projects/fft/build
```

and  **make**

```
Scanning dependencies of target fft
[ 20%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/fft.dir/fft.c.o
[ 40%] Linking C shared library libfft.dylib
[ 40%] Built target fft
[ 60%] Swig source
/Users/simon/Documents/projects/fft/src/swig/python/../../fft.h:6: 
Error: Syntax error in input(1).
make[2]: *** [src/swig/python/fftPYTHON_wrap.cxx] Error 1
make[1]: *** [src/swig/python/CMakeFiles/_fft.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

As you can see I am on macOS (Mojave), the shared library in C compiles, but SWIG can't seem to get along with the function declaration in the header. I tried to remove the `complex` (and use only `double` numbers) and it seems to work, so my guess is the `complex.h` file that can't be found somehow...

Any help will be much appreciated !

Thank you !

Comment: Just the `fft.h` and `fft.i` should be enough to reproduce the error with `swig -python fft.i`, but I couldn't reproduce the error.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, with `swig -python fft.i` I couldn't be able to reproduce the error either, so maybe this is an issue with my `cmake` config files ?

Comment: Possibly.  I'm not very familiar with cmake.  It would be useful to know the options used to run swig.